# Time frame Past Perfect and Past Simple in 1 sentence

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Is it correct to use the sentence 'He knew the answer to the question because he had studied really hard for this test.' as an example to referring to the time indication of Past Perfect and Past Simple in 1 sentence? Thank you in advance!
This came as an afterthought, so I posted this as a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of Past Perfect or Past Simple](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472732/usage-of-past-perfect-or-past-simple)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. This came as an afterthought. I wanted to be sure if I could use this sentence as an example re time indication of PP or PS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been a teacher of English for 40 years, and very often I illustrate the use of these two tenses with similar sentences.
Your example is correct as it shows the proper chronology of the events. The Past Perfect is used to underline the event that happened before the other one   /in the Past Simple/ when the narrative is in the converted order.